# Why title is not changing when using "supportActionBar?.title " with ".addToBackStack" in Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

These are some pics of my android studio

[MainActivity.kt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKt1H.png)

[DashboardFragment.kt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b63vz.png)

[fragment_dashboard.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9Z3O.png)

[Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSkRo.png)

As you can see in the emulator the title has not changed as we clicked the back button, so what's the solution for these problem.

Also don't mind all the comments written ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use navigation components instead of the legacy navigation fragment

you can follow the docs here: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Is more easier to navigate and you can add a title in each fragment.